Лучшая практика установки двух ОС: на отдельных дисках или на одном диске?
Планирую установить две операционные системы(Ubuntu і Windows 10) на один компьютер. Какой вариант лучше с точки зрения стабильности и производительности: установка каждой ОС на отдельный физический диск или установка обеих ОС на один диск, но на разные разделы? Каковы преимущества и недостатки обоих подходов?
*Ubuntu основная ОС.

Лучшая практика - устанавливать Ubuntu в виртуальной машине.

Из коммента выше, Ubuntu в виртуальной машине не плохо, но не всегда так нужно) Вин 10 поддерживает оболочку линукс, тоесть можно использовать ядро прям из системы Вин, там возникают некоторые проблемы, из-за чего использовать систему как полноценный аналог - не получится) Очевидно, установка на отдельный физический диск наиболее удобна) Можно на флешку даже, 8 ГБ флешки хватит для простых задач (это там где БД не пару ГБ..)

В моем случае Ubuntu будет являться основной системой, в нем я буду проводить большинство времени. Windows будет исключительно чтобы иногда поиграть или в случае если нужно что-то протестовать на Windows.

@Ledauph1n в таком случае, если у вас есть второй HDD/SSD, в идеале установить ОС на него, в биосе поставить приоритет загрузки и все) Из под линукс вроде будет читаться диск с виндой, а вот наоборот нет. Я бы сделал именно так

Преимуществ ставить на один диск никаких. У линукса свои типы файловых систем и своя таблица разделов, у винды свои. Я даже не уверен, что так получится сделать без танцев с бубном. Ставьте на 2 разных физических диска. Так ос никак не будут мешать друг-другу и даже если одна навернётся, со второй ничего не произойдёт. А документы и файлы, которые вы хотите, чтобы были доступны из обоих систем лучше хранить вообще на 3-м диске.

Ставим на два разных физических диска. Потом регистрируем Windows в загрузчике Убунты. Ну или, если хочется, определяем загрузку по горячей клавише BootMenu.

Я даже не уверен, что так получится сделать без танцев с бубном. На данный момент у меня 2 ОС на одном диске. Особенно никаких проблем с устновкой не возникало.

"с точки зрения стабильности и производительности" - никакой разницы. На одном диске лишь появляется небольшая вероятность, что винда может сдуру затереть линуксовый загрузчик (да и то это не проблема на UEFI, который позволяет установить несколько загрузчиков), а во всём остальном пофигу

поддерживаю предыдущие комменты) на сегодняшний день можно вообще из коробки ставить 2+ ОС на один HDD.. и проблем возникнуть не должно) но, Я, разделил бы ОС на физически разные HDD) У меня основная ОС Win 10 enterprise, в соседней комнате стоит старый ПК с ubuntu на борте и подключенный кабелем к роутеру) удобно ппц.. когда нужно, просто включаю второй комп и работаю из консоли или VScode Rem.. на винде более медиа контент, игрушки там.. Хотя еслиб не одна игра, я бы спокойно перешел на линукс, выиграв при этом синхронизацию дисков по сети с вторым ПК..
